# sed: remember capture in second expression

Tags: sed, gnu-sed

I am trying to find occurence of captured pattern and pre-pend next line with captured pattern.

For example:

```
...
[line 10] #---------- SOLID: tank_phys.0
[line 11]   Shape {
...
[line 22] #---------- SOLID: head_phys.0
[line 23]   Shape {  
...
```

expected output:

```
...
[line 10] #---------- SOLID: tank_phys.0
[line 11]   DEF tank Shape {
...
[line 22] #---------- SOLID: head_phys.0
[line 23]   DEF head Shape {   
...
```

Here is what I have:

```
sed -rn '/#---------- SOLID: (.*)_phys.0/{n ; s/Shape/DEF <PreviousCapture> Shape/p;}' g4_00.wrl
```

How can I substitute `Shape {` with `DEF tank Shape {` ?

Thanks

GT

Comment: Store the result of the first `sed` in a variable, then use that variable in the second `sed`?

Comment: Please shoe more samples in code tags in your post, it is not clear.

Comment: that will not work if I want to process whole file in one go. The file containes multiple occurences of the pattern I showed. thanks . Perhaps if you show me how you were thinking ?

Comment: Could you check my `sed` solution?

Comment: works perfect, now makes me feel like I know nothing about sed. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a pure `sed` solution:

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat file
#---------- SOLID: tank_phys.0
  Shape {
abcdef
1234
#---------- SOLID: head_phys.0
  Shape { 
12345
gdfg
```

**Command:**

```
$ sed -rn '/#---------- SOLID: (.*)_phys.0/{p;s/#---------- SOLID: (.*)_phys.0/DEF \1/;N;s/\n//;s/ {2,}/ /;s/^/  /p;b};/#---------- SOLID: (.*)_phys.0/!p' file
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
#---------- SOLID: tank_phys.0
  DEF tank Shape {
abcdef
1234
#---------- SOLID: head_phys.0
  DEF head Shape { 
12345
gdfg
```

**EXPLANATIONS:**

```
/#---------- SOLID: (.*)_phys.0/{ #this block will be executed on each line respecting the regex /#---------- SOLID: (.*)_phys.0/
p; #print the line
s/#---------- SOLID: (.*)_phys.0/DEF \1/; #replace the line content using backreference to form DEF ...
N;#append next line Shape { to the pattern buffer
s/\n//;s/ {2,}/ /;s/^/  /p; #remove the new line, add/remove some spaces
b}; #jump to the end of the statements
/#---------- SOLID: (.*)_phys.0/!p #lines that does not respect the regex will just be printed
```

Answer (score 0):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/#---------- SOLID/{print;sub(/_.*/,"",$NF);val=$NF;getline;sub("Shape {","DEF " val " &")} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[line 10] #---------- SOLID: tank_phys.0
[line 11]   DEF tank Shape {
...
[line 22] #---------- SOLID: head_phys.0
[line 23]   DEF head Shape {
```

Comment: I updated the input to make clear that the lines are not always same, so this awk solution does not work,  thanks

Comment: @user1301295, your output is NOT looking consistent in your post shown why `{` is not there for first occurrence of `shape` ? If it is a typo then you would have tried my code I just tested it is working fine only, let me know on same?

Comment: Edit made, thanks.  Coul you explain the code more, I'm only just learning sed and awk is new to me

Comment: @user1301295, sure edited the code as per your need, will add explanation too now in short time, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed -E '
  /SOLID/!b
  N
  s/(^.*SOLID: )([^_]*)(.*\n)([[:blank:]]*)(.*$)/\1\2\3\4DEF \2 \5/
' infile
```